# Bypassing Password Prompt for osascript on MacBook M2 with Amphetamine App

Tags: apple-silicon

I'm using osascript to automate tasks with the Amphetamine app on my MacBook M2. However, every time the script activates, it prompts for my computer password. Is there a way to configure either the script or my system to run the script without asking for a password each time?

Please note that I have no programming skills so don't go too hard on me with the lingo if you care to explain.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The script asks, or Amphetamine asks?

Comment: Please add your script or a representative snippet that illustrates the problem to your question.